# how to get a value from json to build a value into lable in mit app inventor

Tags: android

this is my JSON data I want to pick title value

```
{"id":"5f4ca02e8ce45619eca09707","title":"dashBoard","description":"dash board is showing"}
```

I want to set the title value to the label in it app inventor

[image]

Comment: @ADM, that is native android java but I needed to do in MIT App Inventor

Comment: does [this](https://appinventor.mit.edu/papers/blocksplus18_p13_tang.pdf) help?

Answer (score 0):

this is the process of setting like this

[image]

I refer in this link
http://ai2-test.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/json-web-apis.html

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or, did you mean to edit your question for more information?